# WEKA Java Data Mining training text

Tags: java, weka

I'm a beginner in Weka and text classification. I'm using weka in a java program because i want to use it to categorize my website post's titles. For example:

"How to download video from youtube", "Best android phones 2013", "Microsoft announced a new Tablet for this year" etc...

I have 23 categories: Sport, Technology, Science, Health, etc...

For each category i found 5 websites from which i get my training text. For example the text content of engadget.com's articles is added in Weka for the category Techonology.

Now here is the problem. What kind of text should i add in Weka?

Until now i get all the website's article title, splitted them by the space between words and add singular words to categories (unigrams). For example if a title is "How to fix the computer" this is what i do:

Add "how" to technology, Add "is" to technology, Add "fix" to technology and so on.... (obviously i'm using a stopword list to delete useless words).

But the results i'm getting are not good.

Based on your experience what should i do? Should i:

a) Add the full text of article's title to a category;
b) Add the full text of article's content to a category;
c) Split the text of article's content into singular words (unigrams) and add them to a category;
d) What else?

Thank you.